# Basis of a subspace of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let, $T:V\to W$ be a linear transformation.

If we look at the image of the linear transformation which is a subset of $W$ and also forms a subspace of $W$. The spanning set is a subset of $W$ itself. So, the basis is a part of it.

But, the nullspace, which is a subspace of $V$ and maps to the zero vector of $W$, provides the output that belongs to $W$ set whereas the spanning set belongs to $V$. How is this possible?

Is it not always true that the basis of a subspace must also belong to the subspace it spans? Or am I missing out something?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "provides the output that belongs to W" ? I think you may mean "provides the input that maps to 0 in W"

Comment: I meant the vector we get when we apply the transformation. That is in W.

Comment: what you mean by: "But, the nullspace, which is a subspace of $V$ and maps to the zero vector of $W$, provides the output that belongs to $W$ set whereas the spanning set belongs to $V$. How is this possible?
"? The image of the nullspace (also namely kernel) is the set $\{0\}\subset W$.

Comment: The zero vector $0_V$ in $V$ could be different from the zero vector $0_W$ in $W$. What is the confusion?

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a vector space,then $B$ is said to be a basis for $V$ if:

$(1)$ $B$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$

$(2)$ $\operatorname{span}(B)=V$

So by condition $(1)$ it is clear that $B$ is indeed a subset of $V$.

Now, coming to your confusion.

Consider the linear transformation, $T:V\to W$.

Let, $R(T)$ and $N(T)$ denote the Range Space and Null Space of $T$ respectively.

As you have already pointed out,  $R(T)$ is a subspace of $W$ whereas $N(T)$ is a subspace of $V$.

So a basis for $R(T)$ must be a subset of $W$ and a basis for $N(T)$ must be a subset of $V$.

You seem to be linking the definition of $R(T)$ and $N(T)$ with their basis, but these are two totally different things.

Comment: I want to point that an alternative notation (that doesnt need further explanation) for $R(T)$ and $N(T)$ is just $T(V)$ and $\ker(T)$.

Comment: @Masacroso Yes, I agree that these are the standard notations but I wanted to to continue with OP's terminology.